# Fill DataTable from Oracle Database Table - C#

Tags: c#, oracle, ms-access, datatable

I have successfully built connection string and able to populate table data when the database is Access as:

```
DataTable results = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection thisConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionname))
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from TABLE_A", thisConnection);  //EDIT : change table name for Oracle
                thisConnection.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(results);
            }
```

I am new to Oracle though. Can somebody mention what changes to make in above code for Oracle database?

Comment: yeah but how? @ChrisCruz

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try this;

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Your Connection string");

//Open the connection to the database
conn.Open();

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("your select query");

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Connection = conn;

using (OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
{
  dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
  dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
}
```